# Несколько значений JS html

Tags: javascript, php, html, site

Подскажите, как отправить несколько значений?
Вот код js, отправляю в PHP обработчик. Нужно отправить два инпута.
То есть инпут cpCardNumber, и есть еще второй dateNumber

```
function test(){    
                 
             $.ajax({
    url: "../add_order.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({ card: $("#cpCardNumber").val() }),
    success: function(dataStatus){  
        
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `data: { card: $("#cpCardNumber").val(), date: $("#dateNumber").val() },`

Comment: `data: {formData: $('#id_form').serialize()},` - где id_form - id формы, поля из которой вы собираетесь отправить. Отправится сериализованная форма, но не важно, сколько и каких полей было заполнено.

Comment: это я знаю. мне нужны конкретные поля были, без <form> , уже решил вопрос сам